# asp.net website external bin folder

Tags: asp.net, iis-5

Can I put my "bin" folder with all of its .dll files at a higher level then the IIS Local Path/web root for the site? I need to keep my dll files in a directory outside of my project is this possible, I tried to use a virtual directory but .net seems to ignore it.

Can I use a virtual directory for my bin folder?

**DUPLICATE:** More info provided here: [adding .net code to a classic asp website, can't reference namespaces in .dll file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375887/adding-net-code-to-a-classic-asp-website-cant-reference-namespaces-in-dll-file)

Comment: Carlton, why is this a duplicate? I don't see another.

Comment: This is way-old, but the "duplicate" mentioned actually points back to this question.  This is the definitive version I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot. Maybe the GAC will work.

Comment: Yes the GAC was an option, the one problem there is it would complicate our deployment process. That would be my last resort option.

Answer (score 0):

You can.  You will need to modify the config file for your application to probe the location:

```
<runtime>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <probing privatePath="MyCoolNewPath/bin" />
  </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

Comment: probing.PrivatePath does not allow paths outside of the root ("Specifies application base subdirectories for the common language runtime to search when loading assemblies."), so they're not external

Comment: I agree with John, would be great if you could just say <probing privatePath="../MyCoolNewPath/bin" />, but it doesn't work that way. This method is meant to give you the ability to override global libraries inside of the local folder. In other words this is the reverse of what I'm looking for.